# Результат ошибки 31 возвращен из "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\mt.exe"

Tags: visual-studio, компилятор

Периодически при компиляции проекта появляется ошибка

```
1>mt.exe : general error c101008d: Failed to write the updated manifest to the resource of file "..\Debug\123.exe". @>F5AA =5 <>65B ?>;CG8BL 4>ABC? : D09;C, B0: :0: MB>B D09; 70=OB 4@C38
```

она чередуется с еще одной

```
Ошибка 19 Результат ошибки 31 возвращен из "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\mt.exe".
```

С третьего раза обычно проект нормально собирается. С чем это связанно?

Comment: Помог такой способ.

In Visual Studio, navigate to Tools -> Options from the top menu
Select the Show All Settings option
Expand the Projects and Solutions item in the tree
Select VC++ Directories
Repeatedly click on the New Item button (the yellow folder-like icon) to add each of the following 3 paths to the list:
 
    $(SystemRoot)
    $(SystemRoot)\System32
    $(SystemRoot)\System32\wbem
 
Click OK and restart Visual Studio for the configuration to take effect.

Comment: Вру. Ошибка опять появилась. Тема еще актуальна